# How to use a method from class extending State in another class - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, instantiation

I am able to use a method created in a class that extends State so would like to use the same method in other classes as works correctly.

Method:

```
    await tts.setVolume(1);
    await tts.setSpeechRate(0.5);
    await tts.setPitch(1);

    if (app.txt != null) {

      if (app.txt!.isNotEmpty) {

        await tts.speak(app.txt!);

      }

    }

  }
```

As the class that's exting State class is private, don't know what should I do...

`class _AppState extends State<App>{...}`

Could you help?

I have created an instance of the base class:

```
   app.speak();
```

Get a bug: **The method 'speak' isn't defined for the type 'App'.**

As said, the **speak** method belongs to _AppState's class tho it's private...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```dart
class AppState extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppState({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppState> createState() => AppStateState();
}

class AppStateState extends State<AppState> {
  Future<void> speak() async {
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

class AnotherWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnotherWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<AnotherWidget> createState() => _AnotherWidgetState();
}

class _AnotherWidgetState extends State<AnotherWidget> {
  void anotherMethod(BuildContext context) {
    final ttf = context.findAncestorStateOfType<AppStateState>();
    ttf?.speak();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Notice the `AnotherWidget` is the child of the top AppState.

```dart
void anotherMethod(BuildContext context) {
    final ttf = context.findAncestorStateOfType<AppStateState>();
    ttf?.speak();
  }
```